# Spring Boot 2.2.2 Datasource URL not working for SQL Server 2019

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to doing a test development with Spring on SQL Server 2019, but all I get is the Datasource url attribute issue.

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

As for my yml configration I don't think I set something wrong

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=yap_test
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    username: 'yap_user'
    password: 'P@ssw0rd'
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: false
        format_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        use_nationalized_character_data: true
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            audit_table_prefix: AUD_
            audit_table_suffix: ''
            revision_field_name: REVISION_ID
            revision_type_field_name: REVISION_TYPE
            store_data_at_delete: true
```

for the JDBC Driver i'm using mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope someone can help me figure out what's my configuration problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually added exclude any YML file during jar repackage, so that's the reason why everytime I tried to run it locally it doesn't find the url attribute.

Comment: How do you did this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. there is no problem with property file.

1st of all try to check whether **"mssql"** jar is there or not in your  local maven repository.

if it's there then update your property file as below:--

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

In your Case it should be:--(yml file)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

if it's not there:--

solution :- give the mssql JAR path in the pom then run

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer, but I actually found the answer.

I added exclude yml file on repackage so that's why it forever unable to actually load my configuration